# Java: Finding consecutive numbers within a generated file

Tags: java, file

So, I have created a program that runs in two parts. Firstly, I generate a list of 500 random numbers and store them in a text file. Secondly, I am required to find the max, min, average, etc. However, I am also supposed to find how many consecutive numbers come up. This is where my problem lies. I am not sure how to approach it.

Looking for a place to start.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you go along the array you will keep the list of the following things: current largest seen element, current smallest seen, total of all elements seen so far, ..., the last element seen & total count of consecutive numbers. If current number == last element seen + 1, you increase  the consecutive count. There should also be a flag for the first element in the consecutive sequence, so that, say, `{1, 2}` counted 2 occurrences instead of one

```
last_seen = -1
previous_consecutive = false
for(x in numbers_list):
    if x == last_seen + 1:
        if not previous_consecutive:
            number_of_consecutive_elements += 1
        number_of_consecutive_elements += 1
        previous_consecutive = true
    else:
        previous_consecutive = false
    last_seen = x
```